# Use image as watermark with compressor.js

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, watermark, image-compression

I am using compressor.js for image compression and watermarking. However, only text based watermark seems to be possible to me. I want to add image (logo) into watermark too.

Any idea how to use image as watermark with compressor.js?

Comment: I believe the simple answer is you can't do that with compressor.js, atleast to my knowledge. Why don't you use [watermark.js](http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/)?

Comment: hmmm... I want to make it simple without adding new js for watermark. And I believe with canvas drawImage function, this can be achieved easily, i tried but I am not JS expert and need some help.

Comment: @Krunal - where's your code? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the [drew function](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/compressorjs#drewcontext-canvas), like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/compressorjs/1.0.7/compressor.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="watermark" src="watermark.png" style="display: none" />
  <h3>Input</h3>
  <div id="input"><img id="image" src="picture.png" style="max-width:250px"></div>
  <h3>Output</h3>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var Compressor = window.Compressor;
      var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      var image = document.getElementById('image');   
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      var watermark = document.getElementById('watermark');
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.onload = function () {
        new Compressor(xhr.response, {
          strict: false,
          drew: function (context, canvas) {
            context.drawImage(
              watermark,
              0,
              0,
              watermark.width,
              watermark.height,
              canvas.width - ((watermark.width / 4) + 10),
              canvas.height - ((watermark.height / 4) + 10),
              (watermark.width / 4),
              (watermark.height / 4))
          },
          success: function (result) {
            var newImage = new Image();
            newImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(result);
            newImage.style = "max-width:250px";
            output.appendChild(newImage);
          },
          error: function (err) {
            window.alert(err.message);
          },
        });
      };

      xhr.open('GET', image.src);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.send();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the dividing by 4 is because my watermark image is massive. That's not required.

Here's a screenshot of the before/after:

[image: Before + After]

### Alternative Method

Here's an alternative way to add a watermark to an image:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <img id="watermark" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/71/Corona_Extra.svg" style="display: none" />
  <img id="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1665606855702-144fd49af552?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80%20870w" style="display:none">
  <canvas id="output"></canvas>
  <script>
  
    var imagesLoaded = 0;
    var main = document.getElementById("image");
    var watermark = document.getElementById("watermark");
    
    function imageHasLoaded() {
        imagesLoaded++;
        if (imagesLoaded == 2) {
            var c = document.getElementById("output");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            
            c.width = main.width;
            c.height = main.height;
            ctx.drawImage(main,
                          0, 0,
                          main.width, main.height,
                          0, 0,
                          main.width, main.height);
            ctx.drawImage(watermark,
                          0, 0,
                          watermark.width, watermark.height,
                          (main.width - watermark.width) / 2, (main.height - watermark.height),
                          watermark.width, watermark.height);
        }
    }
    
    main.load = imageHasLoaded();
    watermark.load = imageHasLoaded();
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to recreate your codes above in local and in codepen, but the output never produced. How come? Please have a look (https://codepen.io/Gedanggoreng/pen/eYrxRdm)

Comment: I've added an alternative method, which puts a watermark on an image without using compressorjs. That will work straight away when copied into the HTML part of codepen.

Comment: Hi. I have tried your alternative method and it's working nicely. Thank you for your help.